# AngularJS Somehow sorting two tables with one click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two tables on an angular page, both with clickable headers for sorting. Somehow, clicking headers in either table sorts BOTH tables, even though they have different column names, and different 'orderByField' variables.

First Table:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="clickable colored_text span7 textLeft" ng-click="flagOrderByField='FlagName'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">Flag Name</th>
            <th class="clickable colored_text span2 textLeft" ng-click="flagOrderByField='DateAdded'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">Date Added</th>
            <th class="clickable colored_text span2 textLeft" ng-click="flagOrderByField='Expires'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">Expires</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="flag in FlagList | orderBy:flagOrderByField:reverseSort" style="border-top: 1px dashed rgb(200, 200, 200);">
            <td ng-class="flag.SystemFlag ? 'text-error' : 'text-success'">{{::flag.FlagName}}</td>
            <td>{{::flag.DateAdded | date:'MM/dd/yyyy' }}</td>
            <td>{{::flag.Expires | date:'MM/dd/yyyy' }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Second Table:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="clickable colored_text" ng-click="orderByField='CourseNumber'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">Course #</th>
            <th class="clickable colored_text" ng-click="orderByField='ClassName'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">Course Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="class in classes | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort | startAt:(currentPage-1)*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
            <td>{{::class.CourseNumber }}</td>
            <td>{{::class.ClassName }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I get these two tables to sort separately? (This page also has a bunch of other tables, in tabs that load on tab-click, that all share this same strange behavior.)

Answer (score 0):

Aha - In a bit of quick intuiting, I noted that both tables used the same 'reverseSort' variable. I changed it for the first table to 'flagReverseSort', and set the default in the controllers.js to false; voila! it works as it should. So not only do the tables need their own orderBy variable, but they need their own, unique, reverseSort variable.

Comment: Best to use isolate scope directives for each table. That way you can reuse them if necessary, and you won't have to change variable names to avoid collision.